# How do I select only a few attributes in scoped active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

If I do this:

```
@company.projects.joins(clients).select('projects.id', 'clients.name as client_name', 'budget_id', 'budget_visible')
```

I'm getting only the 3 attributes I'm looking for.

I have also declared the following scopes in project.rb:

```
scope :active, -> { where(active: true).includes(:client).where('clients.active' => true).references(:client) }
```

When I do:

```
@company.projects.active.select('projects.id', 'clients.name as client_name', 'budget_id', 'budget_visible')
```

I'm getting all attributes instead of the 3 I'm looking for.

What am I missing, and how can I select only the attributes I want?

Edit: another detail: when I do `.to_sql` I can see the SQL is perfect and only returns the columns I need, but for some reason when I do `.first.attributes` I see all the columns of Project instead of only the ones I need.